# Can't access superuser in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql, superuser

I can't seem to access my superuser account for my posgresQL database.

Using the command:

```
psql -U postgres
```

I sucessfully login into the user 'postgres'. However, this is not the default superuser. Doing:

```
=# \du
```

I get:

```
List of roles
 Role name |             Attributes              | Member of 
-----------+-------------------------------------+-----------
pgsql     | Superuser, Create DB                | {}
postgres  | Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

So 'pgsql' appears to be my default superuser.

When trying:

```
psql -U pgsql
```

I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "pgsql" does not exist
```

I changed the pg_hba.conf file to the following:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             all                                trust
```

and also tried:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             pgsql                                trust
```

but I still get the same error regardless, that database 'pgsql' does not exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I need to be able to access the database's superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just define database:

```
psql -U pgsql -d postgres
```

if you get error that postgres database does not exist, connect as postgres and list databases with `\l`